# Hike / Trail run northern coast of Creta

Tags: trails

I was recently on Creta and I wanted to do some trail run to see nice sea panorama from the mountains and do something else as swimming and sunbathing.

I've found a (single) path marked as trail on the outdoor maps (Locus app), unfortunately, I wasn't able to go far because the bridge over the highway was blocked by the high fence. Changing my route, I've found myself between the road and another fence, and I've found no other way as climbing over. I understand those fences are built to keep goats away from the roads.

Are they permanent or only temporary? How to find some trail for hiking or running and not found oneself trapped behind the fence? I've checked Komoot or Strava, but I haven't found anything near my stay other than the local roads around the beach or connecting the coastal towns.

Comment: Why not ask the locals?  For example, I looked at Strava and Trailforks for St. Maarten, which doesn't have all that many formal trails.  One obvious trail matching your requirements shows up nowhere on either, but any locals who are into outdoor stuff would know of it.  It's easily accessible, on the south east shore near Phillipsburg.  Similarly, Tahiti seems quite underdeveloped in the inland trails but there are some.  However, that does require you to find the right people to ask.  Asking about walking paths rather than running trails will likely get more responses.

Comment: Lots of tourist spots away from North America/Europe get mostly sedentary tourists who don't upload trails.  And locals who don't see the point either as they know them already.  Do ask about safety, whether from dangerous animals or dangerous people.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica no contact to locals. No Strava segment except along the beach and in the towns. No local known except working in tourism industry and farmers.